# How to install ClockworkMOD Recovery on Sony Xperia Neo V (MT11a)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, rom-manager, sony-xperia-neo-v

I have rooted my MT11a with UnlockRoot v2.4.2 and the "superuser" app has appeared. The tutorial said my phone should be requesting to upgrade 4.0.2.A.0.42 to another number ending in .62, but the Update Center says the phone is completely up to date. I should be getting the BusyBox *after* this update, but the update is not happening. Have I missed a step? The phone is working just fine. I downloaded the ROM Manager, and it is requesting to get "ClockworkMOD Recovery" in order to operate. All this I'm doing to get the cyanogen mod.

Comment: Which tutorial? Please provide a link.

Comment: Flow, the Neo V is "just" the Neo with a 5MP camera, I guess. I don't know if they differ much internally. I think I've successfully installed the CMOD Recovery, I'm trying to work things out now.

Comment: Oh, and I suggest you extend the scope of your question by asking "How can I install cyanogen mod on the Sony Xperia Neo V?"

Comment: I am aware that the V is just a striped down version. But when it comes to installing custom mods small (hardware) differences matter. But it seems that the V has a stable cyanogen mod release, so you should be fine. Feel free to answer your own question if you have successfully installed CM. It seems that the CM wiki has no page about installing CM on the Neo V, I am sure you would get some rep this way :). You can always join the chat and idle around looking for help.

Comment: Unfortunately Sony does not have a recovery partition as expected! Its a boot+recovery combined hence no real CWM per se and if it goes wrong that's the entire handset in unusable state, which generally makes things trickier to flash custom roms etc. The only work-around is to unlock the boot loader, root the handset, and then install a CWM apk which gets installed into `/system` directory and acts a pseudo recovery.

Comment: @t0mm13b Could you drop by the chat?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff as you finally managed to install CWM: Could you answer your own question, add your solution, and then accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I managed to install CWM, but not Cyanogen. I really don't have the time now.

Comment: Unlocking the bootloader is not required for CWM on the Neo V, you just need root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use [x-Parts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pvy.CWMinstaler&hl=de) (formerly known as CWM Installer).

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there any way to uninstall a recovery before installing another?

Comment: Break your phone and have it repaired, in general the technicians will thoroughly flash your phone :) So there must be one but I wasn't able to find it when I needed to.

Comment: Hehe, it seems however that the version X-parts installed was the same version I had. Now I'm backing up my device with CWR to see if I can install Cyanogen 9.0. Any things I should be careful with?

Comment: I think you are confusing your ROM version (4.0.2.A.0.42) with CWM's version. Doesn't matter if you want to replace your ROM by Cyanogenmod anyway :) Remember to put the zip on your SD card before flashing the Cyanogenmod kernel as it doesn't work with the stock ROM or vice versa. Also, Cyanogenmod 9.1 is already out.

Comment: How do I flash the "kernel"?

Comment: You will find a guide to the complete procedure [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1746919)

Comment: Erik, one last thing. I accidentally made an extra backup which didn't even complete because my SD is full, how do I delete that backup, or any other previously done backup using CWR?

Comment: "Now reboot your phone and your phone should have updated to CyanogenMod 9.0 which runs over Ice Cream Sandwich!" I don't have Ice Cream Sandwich. What can I do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4751/discussion-between-erik-and-peter-tamaroff)