# How do I root Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo V?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, sony-xperia-neo-v

I just got for myself this new phone with so many useless bloatware. I just want to root this phone and freeze or uninstall them as they are slowing my device down (even without opening any app, all I have out of my 350mb + RAM is an average of 50mb). Can someone please help me out with a noob step by step guide? Thanks in advance.

SPECS:

Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo V (MT11i)

Android 2.3.4

Bootloader locked (but can be unlocked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [How to install ClockworkMOD Recovery on Sony Xperia Neo V](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28664/how-to-install-clockworkmod-recovery-on-sony-xperia-neo-v-mt11a) this should be possible using UnlockRoot ([download](http://rom.anshouji.com/root/unlockroot22-eng.exe))<sup>1</sup>, which requires a Windows (XP/VISTA/7) computer. The process is described at [How To Root Android Devices Using Unlock Root Tool](http://web.archive.org/web/20130602073825/http://www.androidegis.com/how-to/how-to-root-android-devices-using-unlock-root-tool/), basically as follows:

1. You should have a backup of your data (for safety reasons)
2. Your device should be fully charged
3. USB drivers for the device should be installed on PC
4. USB Debugging must be turned on in the device
5. Connect the device to PC using USB cable
6. Run the downloaded tool, and Click on “Unlock Root”, That’s it.

Another guide available is [Learn How To Root the Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo V](http://web.archive.org/web/20130525140806/http://www.androidegis.com/how-to/learn-how-to-root-the-sony-ericsson-xperia-neo-v/) – in case you are not satisfied with the described method ;)

Good luck!

---

<sup>**1:** The site hosting the tool unfortunately went down. With some luck, one of the results of [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=unlockroot22-eng.exe) has it.</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately for me I have the so called 4.0.A.62 firmware so I have to downgrade to .42 first before I can use root toolkits like the one you suggested :(. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to bear bad news, but many of the links are gone.  Sigh.

Comment: @ScottBiggs Just one. Fixed all the others in just a few minutes, thanks to Archive.ORG :)

Comment: Yes, the former proved very helpful to me on several occasions – hence the latter was not that difficult, and the least I could do :) If you happen to find an alternative link for the missing download, don't hesitate dropping a note, @ScottBiggs – or edit it in yourself :)