# How do I expand my Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My internal storage capacity is running low,  what can I do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/my-internal-storage-capacity-is-running-low-what-can-i-do)

I want to install many apps on my Android phone, but the internal storage is small. How do I expand my Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray internal storage?

Comment: You can't. You can only cleanup things there, but not enlarge it (other than by adding external storage, i.e. sdcard). For cleanup, see e.g. [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/) and [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the proposed. This question is asking specifically about expanding storage on a specific device, while the other is talking about managing low storage situations. While the other will be helpful to the OP, they are not duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but you can't expend the internal storage; all you can do is move on SD card every application that accept that.

To do that, you can go in **Settings -> Apps -> On SD card**, and see that all the apps in that list are checked.
[image]

If any app is un-checked, click on it, and chose **Move to SD card** on its info page.

Also, if you root your phone, you can have complete control over the apps installed on internal memory, delete those that came pre-installed that you are not using, and maybe move more on SD card.

Comment: how do i root my phone?

Comment: See this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28828/668) for details, the method describe there works for Xperia Ray too